# Python Prevent the screen saver

Tags: python

I need to run a code for hours, and the computer I am working with has a (forced and unchangeable) screensaver policy. (It locks after 10 minutes). What can I do to prevent it? Is there any line of code to prevent that?

Comment: Are you using windows?

Comment: For Windows, check these articles: Python screensaver: https://eddiejackson.net/wp/?p=23435     Flags: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate

Comment: @Mike67 thanks! It worked! I added it to the answers so people can find it easily.

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI yes, I am on windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me. I'll just leave it here so people can use it.

```
import ctypes

ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetThreadExecutionState(0x80000002) #this will prevent the screen saver or sleep. 

## your code and operations 

ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetThreadExecutionState(0x80000000) #set the setting back to normal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent screen saver by moving mouse cursor on a fixed period of time, below function can handle cursor moving.

```
import win32api
import random

def wakeup():
    win32api.SetCursorPos((random.choice(range(100)),random.choice(range(100))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a coded solution that you can place in your program (also works for Mac users):

```
pip3 install pyautogui
```

https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/ (Reference)

```
import pyautogui
import time

def mouse_move():
    while True:
        pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100, duration = 1) # move the mouse
        time.sleep(60) # Every 1 min 
        pyautogui.moveTo(50, 100, duration = 1) # move the mouse


mouse_move()
```

Or, without the while loop, run it when required if your program is already within a while loop:

```
def mouse_move():
    pyautogui.moveTo(50, 100, duration = 1) # move the mouse

mouse_move()
```