# Screensaver prevention using ctypes cannot be undone

Tags: python, ctypes, screensaver

I created a simple program following the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63077008, which engages and disengages my screensaver on Win10. It used to work as expected. To allow the screensaver to engage, I'd set the ctypes kernel using this command:

```
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetThreadExecutionState(0x80000000)
```

and would disengage the screensaver using this code:

```
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetThreadExecutionState(0x80000002)
```

As I said, it worked great, and nothing that I know of on my system changed. Now, however, my system is stuck on disengaged screensaver, and though I type in the code for engaging (0x80000000), I cannot get my screensaver to turn back on.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The docs for [SetThreadExecutionState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate) specifically say "This function does not stop the screen saver from executing." so not sure how it is preventing anything.  Those flags should just prevent the display from turning off completely

Comment: Perhaps the display is on, but the "Blank" screensaver is running?